# javascript function return value not woking as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, function

I am trying to understand how to return a value to an attribute within a jQuery call from a function.

I have a solution that works fine but I would like to understand why what I think *should work*, does not.

I have a ASP.NET page with a jQuery accordion.  I want the accordion to open to a specific index based on a value supplied by the code behind file via a hidden value on the page.

In my tests, I got this example to work:

```
var index = $("#Content_Intro_hidAccordionIndex").val();
if (index == null) index = 0;
else index = parseInt(index);
$(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: index,
    event: "click hoverintent",
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

However, doing it like this does not seem to work:

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: function() {
        var ret = $("#Content_Intro_hidAccordionIndex").val();
        if (ret == null) ret = 0;
        else ret = parseInt(ret);
        return ret;
    },
    event: "click hoverintent",
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

So why doesn't it work the second way?

Comment: My guess is active does not expect a function so it does not know that it is supposed to execute it....

Comment: Which accordion library are you using? Does the `active` property accept a function?

Comment: I'm just using jQuery UI's accordion functionality out-of-the-box.  Works great now as long as the programmer (me) remembers to invoke the function! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`active` expects to be an integer, not a function.  It's not a callback, it's just a value of which tab should be active.

You *can* use a function, but that function would need to be invoked immediately and *result* in an integer value.  Something like this:

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: (function() {
        var ret = $("#Content_Intro_hidAccordionIndex").val();
        if (ret == null) ret = 0;
        else ret = parseInt(ret);
        return ret;
    })(),
    event: "click hoverintent",
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

As long as the entire operation results in an integer value, it can be any inline operation you want.  But it has to be invoked and result in that value.  The accordion tool itself isn't expecting just a function and won't attempt to execute that function.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because you assign a `function` (and not **the value it returns**) to the `active` property that has to be an `integer`.

In order to do make it work, you have to *invoke* that `function` immediately (it's called an **IIFE** (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)).

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: (function() {
        var ret = $("#Content_Intro_hidAccordionIndex").val();
        if (ret == null) ret = 0;
        else ret = parseInt(ret);
        return ret;
    })(),
    event: "click hoverintent",
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

Comment: This is correct also but David got to it first. Thanks Erazihel!

Answer (score 0):

Active isn't being set to the returned value of your function, it is being set to the function itself, try this for your javascript

```
function setActive() {
    var ret = $("#Content_Intro_hidAccordionIndex").val();

    if (ret == null) ret = 0;
    else ret = parseInt(ret);

    return ret;
}

$(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: setActive(),
    event: "click hoverintent",
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```